# passing pointers in recursion gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, segmentation-fault, parameter-passing

When returning from recursion it gives segmentation fault...As shows the output below, it is going into recursive calls but while returning there is segmentation fault.. What is the reason.. Am I missing out on some invalid pointer use here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void list(char path[],int i) {
    printf("%s\n",path);
    i--;
    char newpath[]="0";
    if(i>0){
        strcpy(newpath,"");
        strcpy(newpath,path);
        strcat(newpath,"/");
        strcat(newpath,"new");
        list(newpath,i);
        printf("%s\n",path);
    }
    else return;
    return;
}


int main(){
    list("start",10);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
start
start/new
start/new/new
start/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new
start/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `void list(...)`

`char newpath[]="0";`

have not enough memory for copy buffer in it. (only 2 bytes. one for char and other for null character and you are trying to copy more bytes in it).

Also here

```
 strcpy(newpath,"");
 strcpy(newpath,path);
```

No meaning of it. Second one over wright content of `newpath` with latest one.

You need to manually calculate length of buffer and allocate that much.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void list(char path[],int i) 
{
    int len;
    printf("%s\n",path);
    len = strlen(path)+strlen("/new")+1;
    char *newpath=malloc(len);
    memset(newpath,0,len);
    i--;
    if(i>0){
        strcpy(newpath," ");
        strcat(newpath,path);
        strcat(newpath,"/");
        strcat(newpath,"new");
        list(newpath,i);
        printf("%s\n",path);
        free(newpath);
    }
    else return;
    return;
}


int main(){
    list("start",10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: increasing to newpath[256] did solve it! :D but it restricts the length of string. In my application I don't know how long the string is going to be..And I did not quite understand the reason of the enough memory  thing too

Comment: @DharakKharod you need to calculate first and allocate memory dynamically using `malloc`.

Comment: the memset has a wrong size parameter. `sizeof(newpath)` is the size of the pointer.

Comment: Just curious.. while using malloc you have not typecast it into (char*) ... Does it work without it?

Comment: @DharakKharod yes why not. Also it's not required to typecast the `malloc`. it's not good because return of `malloc` automatically/implicitly converted to desired type.

Comment: Oh I thought malloc returns void pointer so we need to typecast to desired type.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line

`char newpath[] = "0"` 
to
`char *newpath = malloc(strlen(path) + 5)`

and include `stdlib.h` library.

This will give enough memory for each variable and you can append.

PS: I am adding 4 because `/new` requires 4 characters in addition to the string in `path`
and the last byte is for `\0` character which marks the end of string.

Comment: you should add 5, because of the `'\0'` at the end of the string